# Excel matching IF statement not evaluating correctly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns in the following structure

```
     A    B
1    49   4922039670
```

I have been able to evaluate `=LEN(A1)` as `2`, `=LEFT(B1,2)` as `49`, and `=LEFT(B1,LEN(A1))` as `49`. However when I try to evaluate `=IF(LEFT(B1,LEN(A1))=A1,TRUE,FALSE)` it evaluates `FALSE`. I have no idea why. I have tried to change both columns A and B to different matching formats but it still just evaluates `FALSE`.

Not entirely sure what Im doing wrong.

Comment: The easiest solution for provided case is `=IF(LEFT(B1,LEN(A1))*1=A1,TRUE,FALSE)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe it is depending on the Version but in my Excel it you cast implicit your number 4922... to a string and 49 <> '49'

Either you make both strings or both numbers, f.e.:

```
=IF(LEFT(B1,LEN(A1))=""&A1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

`""&<a number>` concates an empty string to a number, the result will be a string
you could use function "`TEXT`" or - if you are sure, both are numbers - use '`VALUE`'

```
=IF(VALUE(LEFT(B1,LEN(A1)))=A1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

to make a text should be more stable

Answer (score 1):

Comparing a string (what `LEFT` gives you) with an integer is going to be `FALSE`

```
=LEFT(B1,LEN(A1))=49  //FALSE
```

You want

```
=LEFT(B1,LEN(A1))="49"  //TRUE
```

So:

```
=LEFT(B1,LEN(A1))=TEXT(A1, "0")
```

Or:

```
=EXACT(LEFT(B1,LEN(A1)),A1)
```